# How Can I Avoid This Warning ' A component is changing an uncontrolled input to be controlled. This is likely caused by the value changing from...'?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, forms, input-field, required-field

```
    const AddItem = () => {
  const [user] = useAuthState(auth);
  const navigate = useNavigate();

  const handleAddCar = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const carObj = {
      name: e.target.name.value,
      supplier: e.target.supplier.value,
      email: user.email,
      price: parseInt(e.target.price.value),
      quantity: parseInt(e.target.quantity.value),
      description: e.target.description.value,
      img: e.target.image.value,
      sold: parseInt(e.target.sold.value),
    };
    axios
      .post("http://localhost:5000/car", carObj)
      .then((response) => {
        toast("Successfully Added");
      });
    e.target.reset();
  };
  return (
    <div>
      <Container>
        <Row>
          <div className="col-md-6 mx-auto">
            <h2 className="my-5">Add A Car</h2>
            <Form onSubmit={handleAddCar}>
              <Form.Group className="mb-3" controlId="formBasicModel">
                <Form.Label>Model</Form.Label>
                <Form.Control type="text" name="name" required />
              </Form.Group>

              <Form.Group className="mb-3" controlId="formBasicSupplier">
                <Form.Label>Supplier</Form.Label>
                <Form.Control type="text" name="supplier" required />
              </Form.Group>

              <Form.Group className="mb-3" controlId="formBasicEmail">
                <Form.Label>Email</Form.Label>
                <Form.Control
                  type="email"
                  value={user.email}
                  readOnly
                  disabled
                />
              </Form.Group>

              <Form.Group className="mb-3" controlId="formBasicPrice">
                <Form.Label>Price</Form.Label>
                <Form.Control type="number" name="price" required />
              </Form.Group>

              <Form.Group className="mb-3" controlId="formBasicQuantity">
                <Form.Label>Quantity</Form.Label>
                <Form.Control type="number" name="quantity" required />
              </Form.Group>

              <Form.Group className="mb-3" controlId="formBasicDescription">
                <Form.Label>Description</Form.Label>
                <br />
                <textarea
                  className="w-100"
                  name="description"
                  required
                ></textarea>
              </Form.Group>

              <Form.Group className="mb-3" controlId="formBasicImage">
                <Form.Label>Image</Form.Label>
                <Form.Control type="text" name="image" required />
              </Form.Group>

              <Form.Group className="mb-3" controlId="formBasicImage">
                <Form.Label>Sold</Form.Label>
                <Form.Control type="number" name="sold" required />
              </Form.Group>

              <Button variant="primary" type="submit" className="w-100 fw-bold">
                Add Car
              </Button>
            </Form>
          </div>
        </Row>
      </Container>
    </div>
  );
};
```

I am trying to add an item in mongodb database by a form where I set some default value and required all input field. It is working properly but getting a warning on console "A component is changing an uncontrolled input to be controlled. This is likely caused by the value changing from undefined to a defined value, which should not happen."

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is here:

```
<Form.Control
   type="email"
  value={user.email}
  readOnly
  disabled
/>
```

You can see you're setting the value of this component to user.email, making it a [controlled input](https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html#controlled-components) (where the value is passed in, and controlled from a parent component usually via a state).

an [uncontrolled component](https://reactjs.org/docs/uncontrolled-components.html) is - basically - one where the value is not passed in, and the component itself deals with the value.

I'd guess that your `user` object (or the email parameter at least) is undefined to begin with, and then populates via an API call of some kind.

you either need to always have `user.email` parameter available when this input is rendered (eg. wrap the input in a check so it only renders when user.email !== undefined or add in a placeholder email param when the user object is first initialised), or less ideally supply a value for when the value is undefined. (eg. `value={user.email ?? '-'}` )